# Insert returns "the last operation didn't produce a result"

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

For the following code:

```
with psycopg.connect(host="host_name", dbname="db_name", user="user", password="pass") as conn:
  with conn.cursor() as cur:
    cur.execute("SELECT * FROM table_name")
    res = cur.fetchall()
    print(res)
```

Everything is working fine, but if I try to insert values by replacing

```
cur.execute("SELECT * FROM table_name")
```

with

```
cur.execute("INSERT INTO table_name (column_1, column_2) VALUES (%s, %s)", ("a","b"))
```

I am getting the following error "the last operation didn't produce a result" what can cause it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two ways to handle this:

```
import psycopg2
con = psycopg2.connect(database="test", host='localhost', user='postgres')
cur = con.cursor()
cur.execute("insert into animals values(24, 'fair', 'cat')")
cur.rowcount
1

cur.execute("insert into animals values(34, 'good', 'dog') returning id")
cur.fetchone()
(34,)
```

The first way returns the number of rows affected by the operation per [Cursor](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/cursor.html).

The second way returns the `id` field so there is actually a result.

Answer (score 0):

In case of insert operations `res = cur.fetchall()` is redundant. The error code is self-explanatory here.

```
try:
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO table_name (column_1, column_2) VALUES (%s, %s)", ("a","b"))
except:
    print('error')
```

Comment: How one can be sure that the insert was successful?

Comment: An exception will be thrown in case of error, use try.... except

Answer (score 0):

Cursors are iterable objects，so, If you have multiple execute operations that produce multiple results, you should iterate through the Cursor object when consuming the results, like this: `for record in cursor:`, not only once, which will throw an exception. You can also consume after each resultant execution operation, such as `cur.fetchone()`, and `cur.commit()` after each resultless execution.